# Get siblings of created file in firebase cloud function triggered by onFinalize

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function that triggers when new file is created in firebase storage. Inside this function logic I need to collect every other file located at the same path in array. But I don't know how.

```
exports.testCloudFunc = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(async object => {
  const filePath = object.name;

  const { Logging } = require('@google-cloud/logging');

  console.log(`Logged: ${filePath}`);
  let obj = JSON.stringify(object);
  console.log(`Logged: ${obj}`);
});
```

After that I will try to merge all PDFs in one new file and save it back to firebase storage by the same path. Any help is highly appretiated! Thank you in advance for your wisdom )

Comment: Use the Cloud Storage list API to list files with a common path prefix. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects

Comment: Thank you. I found out that I can collect all files like that:
const [files] = await storage.bucket(bucketName).getFiles();
But how can I specify a path like "bucketName/loads/" ?

Comment: Look at the second code example in the docs.

Comment: Does that mean that all files will be returned at first and then will be filtered by prefix?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [**documentation**](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects#storage-list-objects-nodejs) *Doug Stevenson* linked (2nd code sample for Node.js), you can list objects from a specified folder within your bucket using **prefixes** and **delimiters**.

**Sample** from the mentioned documentation:

```
/**
 * TODO(developer): Uncomment the following lines before running the sample.
 */
// const bucketName = 'Name of a bucket, e.g. my-bucket';
// const prefix = 'Prefix by which to filter, e.g. public/';
// const delimiter = 'Delimiter to use, e.g. /';

// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');

// Creates a client
const storage = new Storage();

async function listFilesByPrefix() {
  /**
   * This can be used to list all blobs in a "folder", e.g. "public/".
   *
   * The delimiter argument can be used to restrict the results to only the
   * "files" in the given "folder". Without the delimiter, the entire tree under
   * the prefix is returned. For example, given these blobs:
   *
   *   /a/1.txt
   *   /a/b/2.txt
   *
   * If you just specify prefix = '/a', you'll get back:
   *
   *   /a/1.txt
   *   /a/b/2.txt
   *
   * However, if you specify prefix='/a' and delimiter='/', you'll get back:
   *
   *   /a/1.txt
   */
  const options = {
    prefix: prefix,
  };

  if (delimiter) {
    options.delimiter = delimiter;
  }

  // Lists files in the bucket, filtered by a prefix
  const [files] = await storage.bucket(bucketName).getFiles(options);

  console.log('Files:');
  files.forEach(file => {
    console.log(file.name);
  });
}

listFilesByPrefix().catch(console.error);
```

---

> Does that mean that all files will be returned at first and then will
>   be filtered by prefix?

As I see in the code sample above, the array **[files]** will store the objects that already pass the filter requirements:

```
const [files] = await storage.bucket(bucketName).getFiles(options);
```